# Backbone.js 'swallows' click event if another event triggers a re-render

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

What I want to achieve is that on form changes, the whole view should be re-rendered. This is to provide a preview of the data just edited, and to hide certain elements in the form when check boxes are ticked.

When the user edits the field and clicks on the button without leaving the filed first two events are fired at the same time: change, click. The change handler first updates the model, which triggers a re-render of the form. When it's the click events turn, nothing happens. I guess it has to do with the re-render because when I comment out the

```
@model.on 'change', @render, @
```

Both event handlers are executed as it should be.

Maybe the click handler is not executed because the click target has been removed from dom and a new button has been added? How would I fix this? I was thinking the code I wrote was 'idiomatic' Backbone.js, but I'm still learning :-)

Here is a simplified version of my code showing the problem:
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oviruz/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us add a few things so that we can see what's going on. First we'll mark the *Save* button with a unique ID:

```
render: ->
  id = "b#{Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}"
  console.log('button id = ', id)
  #...
```

And then we can see which button was hit:

```
save: ->
  console.log('pressed = ', @$('button').attr('id'))
  #...
```

We'll also add a global click handler to watch the `<button>` outside of the Backbone stuff:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', ->
  console.log('global click = ', @id)
)
```

Live version: http://jsbin.com/oviruz/6/edit

Play around with that version a bit and you might see what is going on:

1. Change the content of the `<input>`.
2. Try to click *Save*.
3. As soon as the `<input>` loses focus, the change event is triggered.

   1. That event calls `fieldChanged` which does `@model.set(...)`.
   2. The `@model.set` call triggers Backbone's events, in particular, the `@model.on(...)` from the view's `initialize`.
   3. The Backbone event sends us into `render` which does a `@$el.html(...)` which replaces both the `<input>` and the `<button>`.
   4. The [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) call kills all the DOM elements inside the view's `el`. But, and this is a big *but*, the browser needs to get control again before this process finishes.
4. Now we're back into the event queue to deal with the click on *Save*. But the `<button>` we're clicking is a zombie as the browser's work queue looks like this: deal with the click event, replace the DOM elements from **3.4**. Here the work from **3.4** isn't complete so the `<button>` that you're clicking is half in the DOM and half dead and won't respond to any events.

You have two event queues fighting each other; your Backbone events are changing the DOM behind the browser's back and, since JavaScript is single threaded, the browser is losing and getting confused.

If you delay the `@$el.html` call long enough to let the browser catch up:

```
set_html = =>
  @$el.html """
    <input type="text" id="text" value="#{@model.get('foo')}"/>
    <button class="save" id="#{id}">Save</button>
  """
setTimeout(set_html, 1000) # Go higher if necessary.
```

You'll get the behavior you're expecting. But that's an awful, horrific, nasty, and shameful kludge.

Messing around with the DOM while you're still processing events on those DOM elements is fraught with danger and is little more than a complicated way to hurt yourself.

If you want to validate the field when it changes and bind the view's `render` to `"change"` events on the model, then I think you'll have to do the validation by hand and use a silent `set` call:

```
fieldChanged: (e) ->
  field = @$(e.currentTarget)
  @model.set({ foo: field.val() }, { silent: true })
  // @model.validate(@model.attributes) and do something with the return value
```

If you do a `@model.save()` in the *Save* button's callback, the silent changes will be validated en mass and sent to the server. Something like this: http://jsbin.com/oviruz/7/edit

Or you skip the `@model.set` inside `fieldChanged` and just use `@model.validate`:

```
fieldChanged: (e) ->
  val = @$(e.currentTarget).val()
  // @model.validate(foo: val) and do something with the return value
```

and leave all the setting stuff for `save`:

```
save: ->
  @model.save(foo: @$('#text').val())
```

Something like this: http://jsbin.com/oviruz/8/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can add a little delay before update model in `fieldChange`, you can replace `change` event with `keyup`. There might be many workarounds, but probably best was would be not to re-render whole view on model change.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of backbone to have the views re-render themselves on model changes? Adding a delay before update would save the model before the new value would be applied... Using keyup would validate the model after every key press, before the user finished her input. I would like to understand why my code is failing, and if there is a way to make it work like that (auto-updating view).

Comment: Also there is code in my template checking on the value of certain model fields and hiding areas when conditions are met, I don't want to duplicate that.

Comment: As you said it fails because browser triggers change event before click. And whole point of backbone isn't re-render view on model change. Who said you that? For this kind of tasks you can use some extension like [ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) or [Riverts.js](http://rivetsjs.com/).